# Enable Paypal IPN Listener on developer account

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I have a simple question. I need to setup an IPN Listener on my Developer Paypal account, but could not find where to configure it?! The documentation is old and the website changed?!

https://developer.paypal.com/ --> where to setup IPN-Listener?!

Thanks,

Adam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you'll want to do is go to sandbox.paypal.com and login with the business email and password you created from the developer.paypal.com account. Then do follow these steps:

1. Hover over Name  - Top Right
2. Account Settings
3. Instant Payment Notification
4. Click Update
5. Click Choose IPN settings button
6. Enter IPN URL
7. Select recieve IPN messages radio button
8. Click Save

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you very much. This is somehow weird for me. First I have to login with my paypal account to my developer-account. There I have to create a sandbox accout which I then use to login into sandbox.payal.com account. wtf!!?! ok, Thank you very much! It works now!

Comment: It's a process sometimes, glad you got it bud!

Comment: not working 4/20/20, there's no 'selling tools' option

Comment: Correct. the UI has been changed. Hover over name, account settings [ now selling tools page ] Instant Payment Notifcations